# Workflow association with the list is not recognized by SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I created a very simple workflow with SharePoint Designer. From the workflow details window on SPD I can see that the workflow is associated with my list. I can click "Open associcated list" link and can navigate to the list. However, on the list details window I can't see the workflow. Also, SharePoint doesn't recognize the workflow. On the Workflow Settings page for the list, I don't see my workflow.
Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you published your workflow with SPD?

Comment: My bad. I noticed this after I posted the question. Yours is the right answer, thanks :)